# Alignment of JS Script and HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, alignment

I have a JS `<script>` function and then a HTML`<form>` script and I am trying to implement them into my webpage side by side. However, When I implement them into the page they automatically put themselves one above the other as if there was a `<br>` in my script.[image: webpage screenshot]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>test</TITLE>
<BODY>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://se-flair.appspot.com/4146548.js"></script><form action="http://www.qrz.com/lookup"  method="post" style="display:inline"><b>QRZ callsign lookup:</b> <input name="callsign" size="8" type="text" /> <input type="submit" value="Search" />&nbsp;</form>
</HTML>
```

All of the information I have found says that I would need to download the `.js` from the server and modify some of its code and remove the `<br>`that may be inside it but I am not sure if there is any other way to do it.

Comment: Could you wrap your `<script>` in a div and style that instead?

Comment: Is that an older version of the flair? I looked at my account and it gives my a `<img>` inside an `<a>` for the flair, not a `<script>`.

Comment: @kittycat3141 I am using the SE-Flair on StackApps: http://stackapps.com/questions/2119/se-flair-html-combined-stack-exchange-site-flair

Comment: Any reason you need to use the script method?

Comment: That's what I was wondering. Using a .png doesn't add a new line.

Comment: @kittycat3141 there are three options for embeding the SE-Flair Iframe, Java Script, and `.png` image: http://se-flair.appspot.com/ . I like how the JS and Iframe options are interactively click-able and because the Iframe was messing with some other code in my page, I decided to go with the JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style>
.se-flair {
    display: inline-block !important;
}
</style>
```

Add this to your HTML and it's done.

Comment: The reason I that I edited your post a little bit ago and re-added to your answer what you had deleted, is because I had tried what you said in your answer before you edited it and what you had suggested worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can just wrap the script tag in a div with an id or classname and style it like so:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>test</TITLE>
<BODY>
  <div id='left'>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://se-flair.appspot.com/4146548.js"></script>
  </div>
<form action="http://www.qrz.com/lookup"  method="post" style="display:inline"><b>QRZ callsign lookup:</b> <input name="callsign" size="8" type="text" /> <input type="submit" value="Search" />&nbsp;</form>
</HTML>
```

CSS

```
#left {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the 
 you could do as mentioned before with the float property, i make the example:

```css
 /* Styles go here */ #blockUsr{ float:left; margin: 5px; }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <TITLE> test </TITLE> <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> <script src="script.js"></script> </head> <BODY> <div id="blockUsr"> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://se-flair.appspot.com/4146548.js"> </script> </div> <form action="http://www.qrz.com/lookup" method="post" style="display:inline"> <b> QRZ callsign lookup: </b> <input name="callsign" size="8" type="text" /> <input type="submit" value="Search" /> &nbsp; </form> </body> </html>
```